# Apache Ignite defining pluggable hashing algorithm

Tags: ignite

On page https://ignite.apache.org/features/datagrid.html I've have found following information:

"Unlike other key-value stores, Ignite determines data locality using a pluggable hashing algorithm. Every client can determine which node a key belongs to by plugging it into a hashing function, without a need for any special mapping servers or name nodes. "

How can I define my own hashing algorithm?

Answer (score 4):

In order to do this you can implement `AffinityFunction` interface and provide the implementation via `CacheConfiguration#affinity` configuration property.

Comment: Could you elaborate more please? I am using the C++ client and not really familiar with Java ways. I am guessing C++ bindings do not allow defining `AffinityFunction` and I need to write some kind of plugin in Java somewhere (maybe inside `ignite/libs`?). How do I plug my custom function into Ignite? I actually just need to provide `BackupFilter` to achieve some kind of ACTIVE/PASSIVE behavior.

Comment: In case you want to provide your own affinity function or backup filter, you will need to implement it in Java and deploy into `libs` folder. For now there is no way to provide C++ implementation.